# php echo php to browser, not showing up, security issue?

Tags: php, html, browser, echo

What happen if i use the following?

```
<?php echo "<?php echo date('Y'); ?>"; ?>
```

i could not find an answer anywhere, and when i try it myself, i get:

```
<?php echo date('Y'); ?></td></tr></table>
```

However, it does not show up on front browser, only source.

So my question is, does this affect the html/browser/server in any way?
as i do not want to end up creating a security issue should user post their
own php code in a html only format, like a bio page etc.

Comment: It's just a string that you send. As long as this string does not contain your db credential and whatnot, everything will be fine. You could wrap the string in pre: `<pre><?php echo date('Y'); ?></pre>` so that it shows up in the page

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the chevrons ('<' and '>'), because the browser interprets them as tags.

There are 2 ways you could get round this.

Either use the codes for special characters, so you would do:

```
<?php echo "&#60;?php echo date('Y'); ?&#62;"; ?>
```

Or, an easier way, use the `htmlspecialchars()` function:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars("<?php echo 'hi'; ?>"); ?>
```

More info on the `htmlspecialchars()` function can be found at http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: well, if we are using ckeditor, it does indeed come with html tags.
those function will indeed strip all html tags too, 
was hoping to put that in. maybe if i use preg_replace with /<?php*?>/i, i could remove unwanted tags instead.

Comment: also was using htmlentities and html_entity_decode, so it would decode php tags too.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a security problem and will not have any effects on browser or server, at least not because of PHP code. Even if the string contains PHP code it will just be sent to the client which will not attempt to execute it.

The real problem when `echo`ing user-defined HTML is the risk of attacks such as XSS. Users could include arbitrary scripts or images or scramble the rest of the page by inserting arbitrary tags. In other words: Users could modify the whole page with a single line of HTML.

In general, it's a bad practice to allow such arbitrary input. Have a look at [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) which provides a very basic level of protection.

Comment: strip_tags would turn <h1>this is my bio</h1> into h1thisismybioh1.

Comment: @user3014330 No, have a look at example #1 on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).